# How to use DoNotTrack in Wistia?

Tags: wistia

I don't want to track session details in Wistia for my hosted video. I tried to set the doNotTrack: true in the JS code but my user details get tracked at wistia.
Here is the piece of code

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function()you {
jQuery("iframe").ready(function(){
window._wq = window._wq || [];
_wq.push({
options : { doNotTrack: true} } );
});  
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this request?

Comment: In response to the question "what is http://src.litix.io" Wistia wrote "If you're looking to disable Mux tracking you can do so by setting window.wistiaDisableMux = true, on the page before any videos get embedded" in this Tweet: https://twitter.com/wistia/status/1064915942084354049

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default for your account so all viewers have privacy.

Go to `https://[your Wistia URL].wistia.com/account/profile` then scroll down and activate BOTH "Privacy Mode" and "Anonymize IPs"

Excerpt from Wistia's *Player Privacy Mode* page (link below):

> "Our video player has a special mode called Privacy Mode that only
>   collects fully anonymized viewing data by disabling session and cookie
>   tracking and anonymizing IP addresses. You can change whether this
>   mode is enabled by default for your account in your account settings.
>   This mode makes sure Wistia video viewing is compatible with GDPR
>   regulations."

source: https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-privacy-mode